# MediaWiki - How to use all images from a Category in a gallery

Tags: media, mediawiki, categories, mediawiki-extensions

I have set a description on the file:

```
{{Information
  |description = A cheeky description
}}
```

I have tried to use this [CategoryGallery](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:CategoryGallery) successfully, but I cannot get the descriptions to work:

[image]

I have also used the required extra [extension](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:BedellPenDragon#CategoryGallery_with_captions_generated_from_image_description_files_(requires_CategoryGallery_extension)), they talk about `short_summary`, however this does not exist as far as i can see in [Information template](http://www.gwart.co.uk/Template:Information)

`<catgallery cat="Aubry" bpdcaption="short_summary" />`

So how do I use category images in a gallery with MediaWiki?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cargo may be overkill for this (you didn't mention that you are saving any metadata for all the images).

I personally uses [DPL](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:DynamicPageList3), which allows you do to some cool tricks with categories, you can check the [manual](https://help.gamepedia.com/DPL:Manual), but as for your case:

```
{{#dpl:
category=all_photos
|mode=gallery
}}
```

that very simple example, but you can control the output format within the query (read at the manual i've mentioned).

DPL is built for this scenarios.

Comment: Hey again, I don't suppose you might have an answer for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54655194/how-to-use-imagemagik-in-mediawiki-to-resize-image-uploads

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't mind using a different extension, [Cargo](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Cargo) can do this pretty easily (and lots of other useful stuff as well).

In `Template:Artwork` do something like:

```
<noinclude>
{{#cargo_declare: _table = artworks
| description = Wikitext
| artist = Page
}}
</noinclude><includeonly>
{{#cargo_store: _table = artworks
| description = {{{description|}}}
| artist = {{{artist|}}}
}}
</includeonly>

; Description
: {{{description}}}
; Artist
: [[{{{artist}}}]]
```

And then where you want the gallery (e.g. on a page for an artist), do something like:

```
{{#cargo_query: tables = artworks
|fields = _pageName, description, artist
|where = artist = '{{PAGENAME}}'
|format = gallery
|caption field = description
|show filename = 0
|show dimensions = 0
|show bytes = 0
}}
```

This assumes that the Artwork template is used on files' pages; if you wanted a mainspace page for each artwork, you could still do something similar but would have to introduce a separate `image` field that points to the actual file.

Comment: Ah sam, amazing buddy :) With `{{#cargo_query...}}` how would I target say the category `Aubry`? I've setup cargo now though and everything is good to go!!

Comment: ny thoughts bud :)

Comment: Are you adding things to the Aubry category with a template? If not, I'm not sure there's a simple way; I'd recommend including the category in a template that's used on all the relevant pages. (Sorry for slow reply.)

Comment: interesting, I have never thought about using a template. Simply right now I am, with each upload, tagging the file with a category. As seen here: http://www.gwart.co.uk/File:Sisters_of_Battle_Codex_1997_-_John_Blanche.jpg

Comment: So in theory, with Cargo... I could maybe set up a template for each page I want to do queries on, ie `Artists` and then use these templates as galleries I believe? :O That could work

Comment: I've updated my answer to include artist/artwork example. I'm not 100% sure this is what you're after, but I do think that Cargo can probably give you want you want. I think it depends on how much you need to use Categories for other things… although, that said, I often find that Cargo basically removes my use of categories entirely.

Comment: Thanks Sam for your help. Annoyingly I missed the bounty for everybody. In the end I went with cargo and it was what I was after. But again, just wanted to say thanks

Comment: Oh great! Glad to hear it. No worries about the bounty; all is just imaginary internet points. :-) If you have any more questions come and chat on #mediawiki IRC if you like.

Comment: Nice sam, didn't realise there was such a thing. I've joined

Answer (score 0):

With a little prep, you should be able to use '_categories' if you have set up the wiki's cargo to store categories using "$wgCargoPageDataColumns[] = 'categories';" in the LocalSettings.php

example...

```
{{#cargo_query:
tables=MyTable
|where=MyTable._categories HOLDS 'Foo'
|fields=MyTable._pageName
}}
```

The above should give the name of the files in the category 'Foo'.

To show the images, change the fields to...
|fields=CONCAT( '[[file:', MyTable._pagename, '|thumb]]' )

Comment: above information drawn from: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Cargo/Storing_data